# Why is Laravel's actingAs is not working as expected?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

When trying to test if a user can see some stats, I get some weird results in the http codes

Here is the code that doesn't work

```
public function testUserCanAnalyze()
{
    factory(Game::class, 5)->create();

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $nums = factory(UserGame::class)->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);

    //dd($user->id, $nums->id, $nums->user_id);
    // displays 1 1 1

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('game/analyze/' . $nums->id); //this gives a 403, WHY?
    // $response = $this->get('game/analyze/' . $nums->id); //this gives a 302, LOOKS GOOD

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Instead of getting a 200 I get 403. I think all the ids are correct

If I replace that line with

```
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('account');
```

I get the correct result 200. Manual testing of the url works and if I do it without the id(see below) I get a 404 which is correct

```
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('game/analyze/');
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

My routes are

```
Route::get('account', 'UserAccountController@index')->name('account')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('game/analyze/{id}', 'GameController@analyzeUserNumbers')->middleware('auth');
//Route::get('game/analyze/{draw}', 'GameController@analyzeUserNumbers')->name('game.analyze')->middleware('auth');
```

Thank you

Comment: is this route have a middle ware(('game/analyze/' ) ?

Comment: Can you check if trailing slashes breaks your api.

Comment: see update for middleware + not sure why the trailing slash be a problem if I append the id

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing from !== to != in the controller
Seems like $game has all ids as string not as int

```
if (Auth::user()->id != $game->user_id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
```